# Find string in multiple columns ?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns tel1,tel2,tel3
I want to keep row that contains a specific value in one or more columns:

For exemple i want to keep row where columns tel1 or tel2 or tel3 start with '06'

How can i do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Let's use this `df` as an example DataFrame:

```
In [54]: df = pd.DataFrame({'tel{}'.format(j): 
                            ['{:02d}'.format(i+j) 
                             for i in range(10)] for j in range(3)})

In [71]: df
Out[71]: 
  tel0 tel1 tel2
0   00   01   02
1   01   02   03
2   02   03   04
3   03   04   05
4   04   05   06
5   05   06   07
6   06   07   08
7   07   08   09
8   08   09   10
9   09   10   11
```

You can find which values in `df['tel0']` starts with `'06'` using
[StringMethods.startswith](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.startswith.html):

```
In [72]: df['tel0'].str.startswith('06')
Out[72]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: tel0, dtype: bool
```

To combine two boolean Series with logical-or, use `|`:

```
In [73]: df['tel0'].str.startswith('06') | df['tel1'].str.startswith('06')
Out[73]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

Or, if you want to combine a list of boolean Series using logical-or, you could use `reduce`:

```
In [79]: import functools
In [80]: import numpy as np
In [80]: mask = functools.reduce(np.logical_or, [df['tel{}'.format(i)].str.startswith('06') for i in range(3)])

In [81]: mask
Out[81]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: tel0, dtype: bool
```

Once you have the boolean `mask`, you can select the associated rows using `df.loc`:

```
In [75]: df.loc[mask]
Out[75]: 
  tel0 tel1 tel2
4   04   05   06
5   05   06   07
6   06   07   08
```

Note there are many other [vectorized str methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/text.html#text-string-methods) besides startswith.
You might find `str.contains` useful for finding which rows *contain* a string. Note that `str.contains` interprets its argument as a regex pattern by default:

```
In [85]: df['tel0'].str.contains(r'6|7')
Out[85]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7     True
8    False
9    False
Name: tel0, dtype: bool
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.the functools is useful, but it doesn't seems to  work with Nan value (cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values)
i'm surprised to see that there no easy solution. something like :
    df[['TEL1','TEL2','BOB',FOO']].str.startwith('06')

Comment: The error message: `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values` may occur if the dataframe has NaN values in the index. Generally, it's best to have unique, non-NaN values in the index. To make the index unique, you could use df = `df.reset_index()`. This will move the old index to a new column (or columns in the case of a MultiIndex). Then the method shown above should work.

Comment: If you don't want to change your index, another option would be to index by ordinals instead of by booleans: `df.iloc[np.where(mask)[0]]`.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use dataframe.apply in such situations:

#search dataframe multip columns

```py
#generate some random numbers
import random as r
rand_numbers = [[r.randint(100000, 9999999) for __ in range(3)] for _ in range(20)]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rand_numbers, columns=['tel1','tel2','tel3'])

df.head()

#a really simple search function
#if you need speed use cpython here ;-)
def searchfilter(row, search='5'):
    #df.apply returns the rows or columns as list
    for string in row:
        #string is a number here, so we must cast it.
        if str(string).startswith(search):
            return True
        else:
            return False

#apply the searchfunction to each row    
result_bool_array =df.apply(searchfilter, axis=1) #the axis argument is to run it rowise

df[result_bool_array]
#other search with lambda in apply
result_bool_array =df.apply(lambda row: searchfilter(row, search='6'), axis=1)
```