# How to filter on a pandas dataframe using contains against a list of columns, if I don't know which columns are present?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter my dataframe to look for columns containing a known string.
I know you can do something like this:

```py
summ_proc = summ_proc[
                summ_proc['data.process.name'].str.contains(indicator) |         
                summ_proc['data.win.eventdata.processName'].str.contains(indicator) |
                summ_proc['data.win.eventdata.logonProcessName'].str.contains(indicator) | 
                summ_proc['syscheck.audit.process.name'].str.contains(indicator)
            ]
```

where I'm using the | operator to check against multiple columns. But there are cases where a certain column name isn't present. So 'data.process.name' might not be present every time.

I tried the following implementation:

```py
summ_proc[summ_proc.apply(lambda x: summ_proc['data.process.name'].str.contains(indicator) if 'data.process.name' in summ_proc.columns else summ_proc)]
```

And that works. But I'm not sure how I can apply the OR operator to this lambda function.
I want all the rows where either `data.process.name` or `data.win.eventdata.processName` or `data.win.eventdata.logonProcessName` or `syscheck.audit.process.name` contains the indicator.

**EDIT:**

I tried the following approach, where I created individual frames and concated all the frames.

```
summ_proc1 = summ_proc[summ_proc.apply(lambda x: summ_proc['data.process.name'].str.contains(indicator) if 'data.process.name' in summ_proc.columns else summ_proc)]
summ_proc2 = summ_proc[summ_proc.apply(lambda x: summ_proc['data.win.eventdata.processName'].str.contains(indicator) if 'data.win.eventdata.processName' in summ_proc.columns else summ_proc)]
summ_proc3 = summ_proc[summ_proc.apply(lambda x: summ_proc['data.win.eventdata.logonProcessName'].str.contains(indicator) if 'data.win.eventdata.logonProcessName' in summ_proc.columns else summ_proc)]
frames = [summ_proc1, summ_proc2, summ_proc3]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

This works, but I'm curious if there's a better more pythonic approach? Or if this current method will cause more downstream issues?

Comment: Can you please add some example data that works with your sample code and demonstrates your problem? That will make it much easier to suggest something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find string in multiple columns ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970775/find-string-in-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should work with something like this:

```
import numpy as np


columns = ['data.process.name', 'data.win.eventdata.processName']

# filter columns that are in summ_proc
available_columns = [c for c in columns if c in summ_proc.columns]

# array of Boolean values indicating if c contains indicator
ss = [summ_proc[c].str.contains(indicator) for c in available_columns]

# reduce without '|' by using 'np.logical_or'
indexer = np.logical_or.reduce(ss)

result = summ_proc[indexer]
```

Comment: This works. Since I'm a beginner can you explain what this line does `np.logical_or.reduce(ss)` I'm a little confused.